# Show only some information with file_get_contets PHP

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I've been trying to learn how to use file_get_contents in PHP, and am attempting to use it to display weather on my page from http://www.rssweather.com/wx/us/in/knight/wx.php.

```
<?php
$ref = file_get_contents('http://www.rssweather.com/wx/us/in/knight/wx.php.');
echo $ref;
?>
```

Obviously this shows the whole page I'm referencing on the screen, which is not what I want. I'm trying to show only the current weather, whether that be as simple text or some other form. I've spent some time trying to figure out how to select only portions of a file once referenced with file_get_contents, but I've had no luck figuring it out. I've see people manipulating what appear to be variables from the pages referenced, but I cannot figure out how to access those variables through my code. Would anyone have any suggestions on how best to approach this?

Comment: Use `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath` to process the response from `file_get_contents`

Comment: Did you notice that your the url `$ref = file_get_contents(http://www.rssweather.com/wx/us/in/knight/wx.php.)` that you are using has a dot at the end? change it whit this `$ref = file_get_contents(http://www.rssweather.com/wx/us/in/knight/wx.php)`

Answer (score 1):

As a basic example of how you could use `DOMDocument` to capture the information you want perhaps the following will give you a headstart.

```
libxml_use_internal_errors( true );

$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->validateOnParse=false;
$dom->standalone=true;
$dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
$dom->recover=true;
$dom->formatOutput=false;
$dom->loadHTMLFile( $url );

libxml_clear_errors();

$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
$col=$xp->query('//div[@id="current"]/div');

if( !empty( $col ) ){
    foreach( $col as $node )echo $node->nodeValue;
}
```

### output

> Thunder Storms Temperature: 68°F Humidity:84% Wind Speed:14 MPH Wind
>   Direction:NW (320°) Barometer: 29.94 in. Dewpoint:63°F Heat Index:68°F
>   Wind Chill:68°F Visibility: 10 mi Sunrise:5:54 AM CDT Sunset:7:39 PM
>   CDT   Updated: 10:54 PM CDT SAT APR 29 2017

Updated the code to include `libxml` error handling and added additional flags for `DOMDocument`.

To preserve the original formatting you can get a little better by using `cloneNode`

```
$url='http://www.rssweather.com/wx/us/in/knight/wx.php';

libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->validateOnParse=false;
$dom->standalone=true;
$dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
$dom->recover=true;
$dom->formatOutput=false;
$dom->loadHTMLFile( $url );
libxml_clear_errors();

$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
$col=$xp->query( '//div[@id="current"]/div' );

if( !empty( $col ) ){
    foreach( $col as $node ){

        $html=new DOMDocument;
        $clone = $node->cloneNode( true );
        $html->appendChild( $html->importNode( $clone, true ) );
        echo $html->saveHTML();

    }
}

$dom = $xp = $col = $html = $clone = null;
```

Comment: So the information was contained in the id="current" div? I think I get it. It is displaying the weather properly, however, I am also getting these errors now.                                                                   "DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): Namespace prefix gcse is not defined in http://www.rssweather.com/wx/us/in/knight/wx.php"                                         and "DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): Tag gcse:searchbox-only invalid in http://www.rssweather.com/wx/us/in/knight/wx.php"                                             Would you have any idea what is causing this?

Comment: never seen that error before and I have no issues running this code in test.

Comment: It works now with the libxml error handling! Thanks!